# How to come back to original app after opening a link using href in html5?

Tags: html

I am opening a link using a href but dont know how to come back to the previous page as the url shows in full screen. How should a back button functionality be implemented here ?

```
<div class="mylink"><a href="www.abcd.com">Please click here</a></div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

It may useful:

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function(event) {

    if (event.target.id.indexOf(yourPageId) == 0) {

          //do refresh here.

    }

  });
```